# How do I get rid of the last comma in my C code?

Tags: c

```
for (i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
        if ((vt[i] <= (mid - 65)) || (vt[i] >= (mid + 65))) {
            printf("%d, ", i);
            n = 1;
        }
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("n/a");
    }
```

I want the output to be something like 7, 8, 9, 10 rather than having 7, 8, 9, 10,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might do something like this:

```
const char* fmt = "%d"; /* first item solo */

for (i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
        if ((vt[i] <= (mid - 65)) || (vt[i] >= (mid + 65))) {
            printf(fmt, i);
            fmt = ", %d"; /* subsequent items comma separated */
            n = 1;
        }
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("n/a");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable `n` as a flag. For example

```
for (i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
        if ((vt[i] <= (mid - 65)) || (vt[i] >= (mid + 65))) {

            if ( n ) printf( ", " );
            printf( "%d", i);
            n = 1;
        }
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("n/a");
    }
```

P.S  Check whether the index of the loop should start from 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in simple way with **Backspace** Escape Sequence i. e. **\b**

```
if (i == 100) {        // Just a logic, that doesn't matter
    printf("\b\b ");
}
```

Answer for your logic:
First  \b, moves cursor 96,_
Second \b, moves cursor under comma which is just after 96 i.e. 96,
Third  (" ") space given in printf() will replace/ delete comma (,) with blank space.